# Class design for device driver and graphics

Tags: c++

Banging my head on the wall trying to organize what I feel should be (and probably is) a simple set of relationships between some classes. 
 Basically trying to tie together 3 classes together in a way that makes sense.

Simplified scenario with 3 classes:

1 - LCD device driver
2 - Simple graphics library
3 - Counter display class

What I've got so far in pseudocode:

```
class Driver : public Graphics 
{
public:
    void loadImage(int * image){

        // load image into device memory
    }

};



class Graphics
{
public:

    int image[10];

    void displayImage(int * image){

        // create/ manipulate image here and...

        loadImage(image); //send to device
    }


    virtual void loadImage(int * image){}
};



class Counter
{
public:

    int counterImage[10];

    void makeCounter(int * counterImage){

        //make a clock counter graphic and…

        displayImage(counterImage); 
    }
};
```

Obviously, I've not figured out how to get the `displayImage(counterImage)` function integrated into the `Counter` class. I could `virtual` a version of `displayImage()` in the `Counter` class, but I'm assuming that that would entail that `Graphics` would always have to inherit `Counter`, which I'm not keen on.  Is there a better way to allow `Counter` to access the `Graphics` class functions (ultimately passing through to the LCD driver) while still remaining separate from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use inheritance at all?

Based on the description on your classes, I don't see any specialization / kind of relation between them, which means you you should use composition in this case:

- the graphics `Driver` needs the ability to display some `Image` (a type not present in your example)
- the `Graphics` image loading library needs the ability to load an `Image`
- the `Counter` display should use both a `Driver` and a `Graphics`, both given to it in its constructor, displaying the counter with them.

This concept is called [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), you can get a lot more good articles on it with google. (Basically: OOP and using classes doesn't mean you have to use inheritance for everything)

Comment: Thx.  Mucking around with inheritance for the first time and trying to learn where it makes life easier (and where not).  My main concern with this situation is that different `Driver` classes might be used.  Using composition would mean that `Counter` is tied to the one specific driver.  If i needed to "attach" it to `Driver2` I'd have to write a new class for `Counter` making it "un-reusable".

Comment: To use multiple Drivers, create an interface (`IDriver`), containing only pure virtual methods (`virtual void displayImage(int* image)=0;`), create two implementations (`DriverA` and `DriverB`), and then `Counter` can require an `IDriver` (a pointer or a reference)